# ¿Mi SideBar en React no desliza de izquierda a derecha con el clic?

Tags: css, reactjs, animación

Al darle clic sobre el toggle mi barra aparece como deseo pero no se desliza de izquierda a derecha simplemente aparece, quisiera que se visualizara como el **siguiente snippet** pero no puedo hacer que se deslize al parecer tengo que declarar el ancho en vw, esta pregunta ya habia sido atendida en el siguente [enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32044964/sidebar-toggled-that-slide-to-the-right) pero no puedo solucionarlo al parecer son los estilos, tengo el ancho en `vw` pero no se que pueda estar mal, me podrían ayudar.

```js
$("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#wrapper {
  width: 100vw;
  padding-left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
#wrapper.toggled {
  padding-left: 250px;
}
#sidebar-wrapper {
  z-index: 1000;
  position: fixed;
  left: 250px;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: -250px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: #050545;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  box-shadow: inset -10px 0px 10px -7px grey;
}
#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper" style="background-color:red">
  <div id="sidebar-wrapper" style="background-color:yellow">sidebar
    <div id="result"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="header" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar"> <a href="#menu-toggle" id="menu-toggle">Press</a> 
      <div>This is a serious health setback for me personally, but one of CN's core strengths is that we have a very experienced and tightly-knit senior <span id="counterId"></span>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

estos son mis componentes **SideBar.js**

```
const className = menuVisible ? 'flyoutMenu show' : 'flyoutMenu hide';
return(<div  onMouseDown={this.props.controlarApuntador} className={className} >

            <div  className='menu-lateral'>
                <img src="images/borealis.jpg" 
                            size="mini" style={borealis} />
                <h2><a  href='#'><span>A</span>cerca</a></h2>
                    <hr></hr>
                <h2><a  href='#'><span>C</span>ontacto</a></h2>
                    <hr></hr>
                <div style={{ paddingTop: '10px'}}>
                    <hr></hr>
                </div>
                <div style={{ paddingTop: '10px'}}>
                    <iframe src="https://open.spotify.com/embed/user/emeery/playlist/5ZUCEmqNDcx4HhVaMAgliO" 
                    width="300" height="87" frameBorder="0" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>);
```

y mis **estilos.css**

```
.flyoutMenu {
    width: 50vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #FFE600;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transition: transform .3s
    cubic-bezier(0, .52, 0, 1);
    overflow: scroll;
    z-index: 1000;
 }

  .flyoutMenu.hide {
    transform: translate3d(-100vw, 0, 0);
  }

  .flyoutMenu.show {
    transform: translate3d(0vw, 0, 0);
    overflow: hidden;
    color: white;
    border-color:salmon;
    border-width:1px; 
    border-style:solid;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.589);
    width: 60vw;
    transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
    border-radius:5px;

} // flyoutMenu.show
```

Comment: No tengo muy claro lo que estás preguntando, pero el problema parece radicar en que mezclas React y jQuery para gestionar eventos, lo que no es una buena idea. Debería ser tu componente el que controlase que al hacer click se añadiese o eliminase la clase

Comment: Pues solo quiero que al dar clic en el boton la barra se deslize de izquierda a derecha a cierta velocidad, pero al darle clic no realiza esa transición si no que aparece la barra lateral completamente ! No estoy utilizando jQuery solo React.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buenas amigo no espero esto sea lo que quieres

La idea es que no aparezca la barra para que el usuario no pueda darle al `scroll`

para eso agregamos:

```
body{
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 100%;
}
```

espero te ayude saludos.

> Nota:Esto creo que es lo que quieres cualquier cambio o duda puedes comentarme para arreglarlo o mejorarlo.

```js
$("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
/*Nuevo codigo*/
body{
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}
/*Nuevo codigo*/
#wrapper {
  width: 100vw;
  padding-left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
#wrapper.toggled {
  padding-left: 250px;
}
#sidebar-wrapper {
  z-index: 1000;
  position: fixed;
  left: 250px;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: -250px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: #050545;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  box-shadow: inset -10px 0px 10px -7px grey;
}
#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper" style="background-color:red">
  <div id="sidebar-wrapper" style="background-color:yellow">sidebar
    <div id="result"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="header" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar"> <a href="#menu-toggle" id="menu-toggle">Press</a> 
      <div>This is a serious health setback for me personally, but one of CN's core strengths is that we have a very experienced and tightly-knit senior <span id="counterId"></span>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Ejemplo 2

> Para este ejemplo la idea es que el `wrapper` tenga un ancho de `250px` que lo escondemos con `left:-250px` y lo hacemos visible con `left:0px`
>
> Agregamos un nuevo div que esta oculto y cuando aparece el `wrapper` pone sobre todo y al darle click oculta el `wrapper`.
>
> ```js
> $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
>   e.preventDefault();
>   $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
>   $(".obscuro").fadeIn()
> });
>
> $(".obscuro").click(function() {
>   $(".obscuro").fadeOut()
>   $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
> });
> ```
>
> ```css
> * {
>   margin: 0;
>   padding: 0;
> }
> /*Nuevo codigo*/
> body{
>   overflow: hidden;
>   width: 100%;
> }
> /*Nuevo codigo*/
> #wrapper {
>   width: 100vw;
>   padding-left: 0;
>   -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
>   -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
>   -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
>   transition: all 0.5s ease;
>   position:fixed;
> }
> /*#wrapper.toggled {
>   padding-left: 250px;
> }*/
> #sidebar-wrapper {
>  
>   position: fixed;
>   left: 250px;
>   width: 250px;
>   height: 100%;
>   left: -250px;
>   overflow-y: auto;
>   background: #050545;
>   -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
>   -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
>   -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
>   transition: all 0.5s ease;
>   box-shadow: 10px 0px 10px -7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
>    z-index: 1000;
> }
> #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
>   left: 0px;
> }
> .obscuro{
>   position:fixed;
>   width:100%;
>   height: 100%;
>   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
>   z-index: 500;
>   display: none;
> }
> ```
>
> ```html
> <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
>
> <div id="wrapper" style="background-color:red">
> <div class="obscuro">
>
> </div>
>   <div id="sidebar-wrapper" style="background-color:yellow">sidebar
>     <div id="result"></div>
>   </div>
>   <div id="header" class="container-fluid">
>     <div class="navbar"> <a href="#menu-toggle" id="menu-toggle">Press</a> 
>       <div>This is a serious health setback for me personally, but one of CN's core strengths is that we have a very experienced and tightly-knit senior <span id="counterId"></span>
>
>       </div>
>     </div>
>   </div>
> </div>
> ```

Comment: gracias por la respuesta, disculpa la tardanza trato de aplicarlo en React., gracias por el dato!